# layout using blueprint

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I just started learning blueprint css , with the tutorial [a closer look at blueprint css](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/a-closer-look-at-the-blueprint-css-framework/)
,writing css for my blog , i am running into the problem that the whole site comes to the left and a lot of space is left on the right side of the site , how is it possible to equally distribute the blank space on right and left and get the content on the middle , like most normal sites/ blogs do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prepend-x and append-x classes did the trick for me ,but i am not sure if its the right way also its not fluid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Blueprint Grid Generator.  (Note: it is unsupported)

http://bgg.kematzy.com/

Traditionally, you would set a `width` on the `<div class="container">` and then add `margin:0 auto`, which centers the whole thing.